# JFreeChart set labels for error

Tags: java, jfreechart

I'm using JFreeChart to graph some data, and I've set it up so that the graph shows my standard error for each point as such:
[image: Graph]

The label shows the Y value for each point, but I'd like to be able to show the Y value for the standard errors as well. Furthermore, is there a way to make it so this data only shows up if hovered over with the mouse?

This is the code I use to add both the error and the labels:

```
XYErrorRenderer renderer = new XYErrorRenderer();
renderer.setBaseLinesVisible(true);
renderer.setBaseShapesVisible(true);
renderer.setBaseItemLabelGenerator(new StandardXYItemLabelGenerator("{2}",
    NumberFormat.getNumberInstance(),NumberFormat.getNumberInstance()));
renderer.setBaseItemLabelsVisible(true);
chart.getXYPlot().setRenderer(renderer);
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`XYErrorRenderer`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/renderer/xy/XYErrorRenderer.html) inherits its implementation of [`drawItemLabel()`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/renderer/xy/AbstractXYItemRenderer.html#drawItemLabel-java.awt.Graphics2D-org.jfree.chart.plot.PlotOrientation-org.jfree.data.xy.XYDataset-int-int-double-double-boolean-) from the abstract parent, which knows nothing about the error bars. You'll need to override `drawItem()` in a custom renderer subclass to draw the extra labels. The [source](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/src-html/org/jfree/chart/renderer/xy/AbstractXYItemRenderer.html#line.1657) for `drawItemLabel()` may serve as a guide.

Addendum: A less ambitious alternative would be to display the error range in a tooltip. The custom [`StandardXYToolTipGenerator`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/labels/StandardXYToolTipGenerator.html) below specifies a custom format string and overrides `createItemArray()` to supply the relevant *y* values from the dataset. As your `XYDataset` is a `YIntervalSeriesCollection`, you can cast it as shown below.

[image]

```
renderer.setBaseToolTipGenerator(new StandardXYToolTipGenerator(
        "{0}: {1}…{2}", NumberFormat.getInstance(), NumberFormat.getInstance()) {
    @Override
    protected Object[] createItemArray(XYDataset data, int series, int item) {
        YIntervalSeriesCollection d = (YIntervalSeriesCollection) data;
        Object[] result = new Object[3];
        double y = d.getYValue(series, item);
        result[0] = getYFormat().format(y);
        double min = d.getStartYValue(series, item);
        result[1] = getYFormat().format(min);
        double max = d.getEndYValue(series, item);
        result[2] = getYFormat().format(max);
        return result;
    }
});
```

Comment: Can you use a tooltip for this?

Comment: Yeah a tooltip is what I would prefer to do actually. I have no idea how to make a custom subclass though so I might just call it quits

Comment: That gives me an error of " Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ClassCastException: org.jfree.data.xy.YIntervalSeriesCollection cannot be cast to org.jfree.data.xy.XYIntervalSeriesCollection " on the 5th line